# Flutter Bloc State Change not updating & notifying the UI what was my mistake?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

This was my code to change the state. If I uncomment Future.delayed everything works as expected. But I was trying to achieve without that.

```
void addExpense(
  UpdateExpense event, Emitter<RegisterState> emit) async {
emit(Loading());
// await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10)); --> works If I uncomment this line
emit(Added(
    event.expenseMaster, event.yourExpenses, event.filteredexpenses));
```

}

Comment: does it work with `seconds: 3`

Comment: yes. works even with milliseconds:50

Comment: try using await emit.for

Answer (score 1):

That is a common issue when using flutter_bloc. When I encounter this problem, I usually solve it in the same way you did.

In this ticket they talk about it.
https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/1392

> @Mizhek this is most likely related to a currently existing issue
> that's being worked on. We'll get back with details once that's
> solved. Thanks for your patience